# What is more efficent: several insert vs single insert with union

Tags: performance, postgresql, insert

I have a large table (~6M rows, 41 cols) in Postgresql as follows:

```
id | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 | ... | answer40
1  | xxx     | yyy     | null    | ... | null
2  | xxx     | null    | null    | ... | null
3  | xxx     | null    | zzz     | ... | aaa
```

Note that there are many empty columns in every rows and I only want those with data

I want to normalize it to get this:

```
id | answers
1  | xxx
1  | yyy
2  | xxx
3  | xxx
3  | zzz
...
3  | aaa
```

The question is, what is more efficient / fast, several inserts or a single insert and many unions?:

Option 1

```
create new_table as 
select id, answer1 from my_table where answer1 is not null
union 
select id, answer2 from my_table where answer2 is not null
union 
select id, answer3 from my_table where answer3 is not null
union ...
```

Option 2

```
create new_table as select id, answer1 from my_table where answer1 is not null;
insert into new_table select id, answer2 from my_table where answer2 is not null;
insert into new_table select id, answer3 from my_table where answer3 is not null;
...
```

Option 3: is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 should be faster.

Wrap all the statements in a `begin-commit` block to save the time on individual commits.

For faster selects make sure that the columns being filtered (e.g. `where answer1 is not null`) have indexes